# checkbox mysql/php output. How do I check ID's between 2 tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one with a infinite list of Names and IDs.

The first is the list of Names and their ID.

```
NameID   ~   Name
1            Bob
2            Jon
3            Peter
4            Simon
```

The second table I have is a list of ID's in a linking table, so I can associate what name's belong to a House, for example.

```
NameID   ~   HouseID
1            1
2            2
3            3
4            4
```

I am outputting the Names as checkboxes in a while-loop, and inserting them into my database with no problems with a foreach loop.

The problem I am facing is checking Names and Houses against each other. I want to check the checkbox if the ID exists in Houses. i.e with a simple variable if.

```
if ($intNameID = $xxx) { $checked  = 'checked="checked"'; } else { $checked = ''; }
```

The problem I am facing is understanding how I can deal with these two tables, where Names is currently in a while-loop. I've tried selecting my Houses ID's with a sql statement, but stumped how I can check what ID's have been added to my linking table....

Any help with semantics or example code is appreciated.

Comment: Your description of your database layout doesn't seem to make sense - surely you should have a table of `names`, a table of `houses`, and either a column in `houses` for `NameID` or (more likely) a column in `names` of `HouseID`. This may be what you already have, but if so your diagram of the tables is not very well explained...

Comment: Well, as the database is quite complicated I neglected to leave out several schema to avoid massive confusion. The holding table I have has 5 rows of ID's linking together several tables with joins, etc.

Comment: Please explain exactly what columns and values your result set contains, and how you want to display the data (i.e. what the condition for generating `checked="checked"` is)

Comment: I have two tables, table1, and table2. table 1 is outputting the ID of the Name, and the Name in a checkbox loop. I have table2, which holds ID's, containing the ID's from table1 that have been added to it. I want to check the checkbox (With my IF statement) IF my ID exists in Table 2. (Table1 has the constant ID's)

Comment: I am still not 100% clear on exactly what your code does/what your problem is, but I wonder if it could be to with `if ($intProjectTemplateID = $intProjectTemplateIDCheck)` - should it be `if ($intProjectTemplateID == $intProjectTemplateIDCheck)` (double equals)? At the moment you are evaluating an assignment as a boolean, which will evaluate the right-hand side of the expression as a boolean, which will probably result in `TRUE`, unless `$intProjectTemplateIDCheck` is `0`, an empty string `''`, or some other value that evaluates to `FALSE`

Comment: $intProjectTemplateIDCheck is an array(?) see here: as a definition from my SQL $intProjectTemplateIDCheck=$data2['projectTemplateID']; - thought about using in_array. echo $intProjectTemplateIDCheck; gives '16', my first ID only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4977/discussion-between-smacfadyen-and-daverandom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code rewritten so that it works, with some more sensible variable names, and a few unnecessary variables removed:

```
<?php

  $query1 = "SELECT projectTemplateID, projectID
             FROM projectTempList
             WHERE projectID = '$intProjectID'";
  $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
  $arrProjectTemplateIDCheck = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $arrProjectTemplateIDCheck[] = $row['projectTemplateID'];
  }

  $query2 = "SELECT projectTempID, projectTempName
             FROM projectTemplates";
  $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $checked = (in_array($row['projectTempID'],$arrProjectTemplateIDCheck)) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="recharge_costs[]" value="'.$row['projectTempID'].'"'.$checked.' /> '.$row['projectTempName']." <br />\n";
  }
```